# git-merge-base returns only one commit

Tags: git, git-merge

When I merge between branches, git does a recursive merge with conflicts, putting in `<<<<<<< Temporary merge branch x` blocks.

I abort the merge, and then do `git merge-base <source-commit> <target-commit>`, but it returns only one SHA1.

Is it possible to find out what the multiple base commits are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the `--all` option to `git-merge-base`.  From the documentation:

```
-a, --all
    Output all merge bases for the commits, instead of just one.
```

This will show all the merge bases that will be used to create a temporary tree as a recursive merge base.

For example, consider some branches 'A' and 'B' that were criss-cross merged:

```
       3a4f5a6 -- 973b703 -- a34e5a1 (branch A)
      /        \ /
7c7bf85         X
      \        / \
       8f35f30 -- 3fd4180 -- 723181f (branch B)
```

It's clear that branches A and B have two common ancestors that were involved in a criss-cross merge:  `3a3f5a6` and `8f35f30`.  `git-merge-base` will choose *one* of the common ancestors as a merge base, but using the `--all` flag will include both:

```
% git-merge-base A B
3a3f5a6ec1c968d1d2d5d20dee0d161a4351f279
% git-merge-base --all A B
3a3f5a6ec1c968d1d2d5d20dee0d161a4351f279
8f35f30bfe09513f96cf8aa4df0834ae34e93bae
```

In this situation, as you note, `git-merge-recursive` would merge the two merge base to create a virtual commit that will be used as the actual common ancestor for the three-way merge algorithm.

Comment: Perfect, I missed seeing that in the docs, I'll give that a go.  In your comments it seems you said 973b703 and 3fd4180 are the common ancestors.  Are they not 3a4f5a6 and 8f35f30?

Comment: Hah, yes, pardon me.  My writeup was incorrect, I evidently couldn't read the graph *or* the tool's output below.  Edited.

Comment: In the ideal case, all merge bases have identical trees and the intermediate merge product is the same as any of its inputs.  In practice, occasionally not, as you (OP) found! :-)  One other note, a while back I checked the code for merge-recursive: if there are three or more merge bases, the process is actually iterative on those bases.  That is, merge first gets the `--all` list, then merges the first two of those, then repeatedly merges each additional entry into the merge result.

Comment: That's exactly right.  And... when merging your merge bases _those_ could have been criss-cross merged.  So your merge bases may need a virtual merge base...  It's recursive merging all the way down.  :)

Answer (score 0):

For a note on how to re-do the merge of one specific file using one specific base, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37078105/1256452) to [your related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37049055/1256452).  [Historical note: the OP deleted the question, but has now resurrected it; I had the answer here but it belongs there; hence all these links....]

Comment: Thanks for your time, I've undeleted the question you're referring to, feel free to move this answer over :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37049055/git-choose-simpler-base-in-recursive-merge