# git choose simpler base in recursive merge

Tags: git, git-merge

When I merge between branches, git does a recursive merge with conflicts, putting in `<<<<<<< Temporary merge branch x` blocks.  It's a bit nasty, resulting in 25 conflicts requiring manual intervention in kdiff3.

I then do a git merge-base, which returns just a single SHA1 (see [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37048823/git-merge-base-returns-only-one-commit) if you could help me understand why).

If I manually build up a 3-way merge in kdiff3 using the code from that commit as the base, it's much simpler, with only 2 straightforward conflicts to manually resolve.

Is there any way I can do this with standard git commands, rather than having to manually build up my own merge for the file?

Comment: Did you try specifying different merge strategies (`-s`) and/or options for them (`-X`) to `git merge`?  See `git help merge` for more info. I'd start with `git merge -s resolve` and `git merge -s recursive -X patience` and may be various `diff-algorithm`s with `-s recursive`.

Comment: I had a suspicion the other merge strategies may be able to help, particularly "resolve".  However I was hesitant to do so at the time as I was in a hurry and didn't want to introduce any issue from not understanding things correctly.  Hopefully by the time this next happens I'll be more clued up on it!

Answer (score 1):

[Moved back from [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37048823/1256452), now that this question is back :-) ... and I'll leave just a link there rather than deleting that answer entirely.]

It's somewhat klunky, but you can run [the `git merge-file` command](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge-file.html) after manually extracting the desired base, local, and other file-versions.  This gives you the most control, and I think it might be nice if Git provided a small helper program to run it.

There is `git checkout -m`, but see below.

That is, we should be able to do:

```
git merge --no-commit <args>
```

and then regardless of what state we get, including icky cases like the recursive merge that have installed a "virtual merge base" as the common base in the index, we should be able to do:

```
git re-merge [options] <path>
```

which by default would extract base, local, and other from the current index and re-attempt the merge.

This default is exactly the same as `git checkout -m -- <path>`, so why would this proposed helper be any use?  Well:

1. Note that `git checkout` can also do `--ours` (resolve using local) and `--theirs` (resolve using other).  This proposed command would have `--our`s/`--local` and `--theirs`/`--other`, which would extract those versions but unlike `git checkout`, *not* mark the conflict resolved.

   The idea here is that with the conflict not yet marked resolved, you can view `git diff` output conveniently.
2. It would have `--union` (which `git merge-file` also has but `git checkout` does not).  Union merge is rarely useful, but in those rare cases when it *is* useful, it sure would be nice to have the computer do it.
3. Here's the key item for this particular case: It would have some way to specify the base.  For instance, `--base <tree-ish> [--basepath <path>]` would disregard the index's base blob and take the base from the given `<tree-ish>`.  The default `<path>` would be the same as the file in the current directory, so we need a way to address rename cases.  This is what `--basepath` would do, or perhaps `<tree-ish>` could just be `<tree-ish-or-blob>` so that `--base HEAD~15:path/to/different/name` works.

This is, again, just a minor wrapper around `git merge-file`.  Its chief virtue is allowing you not to have to know how to extract blobs from the index, make a bunch of temporary files, and then clean up those temporary files.  Also, because it never resolves anything (unlike `git checkout`), it "feels less final", or at least it does to me.