# .gitattributes merge strategy not working

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I'm using a merge strategy in .gitattributes to preserve files during merges. I also used `git config --global merge.ours.driver true;` to set the driver in my config (I checked the config for `[merge "ours"] driver = true` and it is there).

My merge strategy is set correctly:

```
src/public/bundle.js merge=ours
src/public/main.min.css merge=ours
server/middlewares/https_redirect.js merge=ours
```

Yet when I merge, I am still getting the files from the branch being merged.

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What you need is a custom "merge strategy"

See [git: How do I add a custom merge strategy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23140240/1256452)  (Edit to add: writing a merge strategy handler is much harder than writing a custom merge driver.  But it's the only way to get the behavior I believe you want.)

#### What you have is a custom merge driver

Your setup does seem correct (albeit a bit "cheat-y", using `/bin/true` or the shell built in equivalent to just leave the `%A` file alone and exit successfully :-) ).  But I suspect you're running afoul of the usual problem, which is:

**Git only invokes a three-way merge driver if there are *two diffs to combine.***

That is, assume we're actually doing a three-way merge.  This means there is a merge base version of some file, such as `src/public/bundle.js`, since there is a merge-base commit that differs from the two branch tip commits.  We're on some branch, whose tip commit is `1111111`, and we're merging some other commit whose hash ID is `2222222` and `git merge-base 1111111 2222222` is `bbbbbbb`.  Hence Git has done `git diff bbbbbbb 1111111` to get the change from base to ours, and `git diff bbbbbbb 2222222` to get the change from base to theirs.

The base version of `src/public/bundle.js` is the one in commit `bbbbbbb`.  But, maybe the diff from `bbbbbbb:src/public/bundle.js` to `1111111:src/public/bundle.js` is *empty*, while the diff from `bbbbbbb:src/public/bundle.js` to `2222222:src/public/bundle.js` is *non-empty*.

In this case, Git *doesn't* do a three-way merge of the file.  It doesn't have to, so it doesn't bother.  It never invokes your custom merge driver at all; it just grabs the `2222222` version of the file and says "I'm done, all merged!"

This is true whether you let Git use its own built-in merge code, or specify a custom driver: it never bothers *invoking* the merge code at all when it can—or thinks it can—get away without doing a merge at all.  It just takes the one changed version and calls it good.

(Personally, I think this is wrong / a bug, but Git has done it this way for many years, and the Git folks seem not inclined to change it.)

Comment: I appreciate the response but not sure I follow entirely. This has worked countless times in the past, which leads me to believe it might have something to do with the base version you mentioned (`bbbbbbb`). What is that exactly? Recently I reformatted my computer, and so I pulled everything down that was previously working. Is this occurring b/c 'bbbbbbb' already existed when I cloned the repo? Should I remove it from tracking and from origin, then start over again?

Comment: If you run `git merge-base HEAD <otherbranch>` you'll get the ID of the merge-base commit. You can then run the two separate `git diff` commands to predict how Git will merge the files. These depend strictly on the *commit graph*. For much more on merging and merge bases, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/14961255/1256452 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/37048823/1256452

Comment: I have never used `git merge-base` before and don't intend to at this point. It seems to me that this 'base commit' might be the issue. I.e. it existed in Github already when I cloned the repo. This post seemingly points out the same issue: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181522/why-is-gitattributes-applied-only-to-files-added-to-repo-after-defining-it.

Comment: That particular Q&A doesn't have enough information in it to diagnose the root cause (nor does yours, really—that's why I point to `git merge-base`; *finding* the three commit IDs, and then diffing the merge base against the two branch tips, will produce enough information).

Comment: Ok so what I did to fix this was make a merge-base that would diff from the two branches in question (production vs. dev). For both branches, I deleted all the files that needed to be preserved, removed tracking, committed, then merged both branches (both ways - not sure if this was necessary but I did it anyways). I then tested the merge-base to ensure it was current (w/o the files in question). After that, I added the files-to-be-preserved back in, committed both branches, then merged dev into production again, and the production files were preserved. Thank you very much torek..you saved me.

Comment: i see this and try but this is not workd for me sooo plzz any help you? marge time both file marge how to solved?

Comment: @kiran.ray: I have no idea what you are asking. The answer above merely points out that merge *drivers* don't get invoked in some situations.

Comment: gitignore or gitattribute can't working for me

Comment: @kiran.ray: `.gitignore` (note the leading dot in the file name) is for making `git status` stop complaining about untracked files. This has nothing to do with merging. `.gitattributes` (note leading dot and final `s`) is for defining particular things about particular pathnames and hence for doing particular tricks with *tracked* files. These are very different. If you have a question, see [ask].