# Force Git to always choose the newer version of specific file during a merge? Or commit to only specific branch?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I am a single developer for my project.

In development I use one file `buildnumber.txt` which I need to have always the latest, despite the branch.

Given a merge command:

```
git merge featureBranch --no-ff
```

Can I specify somewhere that in case of file `buildnumber.txt`, or some other file, Git must always use the newer version?

This would be similar to `.gitignore`, but for resolving of such merge conflicts.

Alternatively, **is there a way to maybe specify** that file `buildnumber.txt` will be stored only in branch `master`?  When I modify it in a branch other than `master`, it should be ignored, so I have to switch to `master` and check it in there?

Comment: Can you show a [mre] where this doesn't work as you expect?

Comment: You could define a custom merge-driver. The driver receives the ancestor version, the current version and the other branch version. Implement the logic to decide which version is the latest and overwrite the current version with the latest version.

Comment: Have a look at `git rerere`, it allows you to record merge preferences. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, you can't do that (any of those three things, really).  The longer answer is still no, but explains *why*.

The first problem you have here is that files, in Git, don't *have* dates.  That's perhaps not such a big problem because Git doesn't *store* files in the first place: Git stores *commits*.  Commits *do* have dates, and then commits have files as well, so you could just use the *commit* date as the pseudo-date of each of the files within the commit.  You could then pick the newest *commit*'s version of the file.  Merging works by *commits* so the fact that it's the commit that has the date should (logically) not be a problem here (though note that physically *accessing* the commit date *would be* a big problem, once you get down to this level).

But this still isn't really want you want—and in any case, there's no mechanism for this built into Git.  Git isn't *interested* in dates during merging.  Git is interested only in *file content*.  You could attempt to use [ElpieKay's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65966610/force-git-to-always-choose-the-newer-version-of-specific-file-during-a-merge-or#comment116635081_65966610) of applying a [merge driver](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) (this link goes to the `gitattributes` documentation, which is where you will see a description of merge drivers), but it turns out this is not a good approach either.  See [.gitattributes merge strategy not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41640602/1256452) for an explanation about *why* it's not so good.  (The TL;DR part is that your custom merge driver is *not used* unless there *is some merging to be done*, and sometimes there isn't any merging to be done.  In one case this works in your favor, and the other case, it fails.)

In fact, the *best* approach is almost certainly to *not store the build version number in Git at all*.  If you have a work-tree file named `version.txt` that is not in any commit at all, this will simply be an untracked file that you can keep out of all commits.  Changing from one commit to another will not touch this file, as it is never part of the repository.  Checking out a branch changes which commit you're using, but since the file isn't in the commit, it won't be copied out to your work-tree.  It's too late to do this with a file that you've already included in existing commits, since those commits literally cannot be changed, but you can either rewrite your repository history, or just change the name of the file.

To keep the untracked file untracked, it will help to list its name in a `.gitignore` file.  Note that listing a file in `.gitignore` has no effect if that file is already tracked, i.e., is in Git's index.  (The answer to the question of when a file is in Git's index is rather long.)